# Audio over HDMI not working on Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio, hdmi

I have recently acquired a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. The audio doesn't work and having looked at other people's comments online I am not the only one having this problem.

I have tried the things that have been advised by other people, but because my knowledge of coding is limited I am not able to really give much info.

Comment: Is it just audio over HDMI or audio through the 3.5mm jack? What operating system are you using? It could be you need to change something in the settings relating to audio. Trying different combinations of HDMI cables and displays might also be worth a go.

Comment: The 3.5mm works when I plug the headphones in. Using Debein, can't spell it and NOOBS. I have raspberian as well. Though i may be completly butchering the spellings of the words

Comment: Please describe _what_ you have done, _what_ the result was, and _how_ that differed from the result you expected.

Comment: Bex. The things that are described by Vader are the things in which need to be done. The only thing that seems to have been left out of what he/she was sugesting is that you must restart the Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a Terminal window and run:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

In `raspi-config` select `Advanced Options` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key select Audio and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. By default I think the option is Auto but you should try changing the option so it forces audio through HDMI then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enable that mode. Exit `raspi-config` by pressing the right arrow followed by selecting `Finish`.

If that still does not work you will need to edit the config.txt file:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Then in the file set `hdmi_drive=2`, this means removing the `#` before `hdmi_drive=2`. This un-comments that piece of code and means that it will run. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the file and press the <kbd>Y</kbd> key twice.

A final thing you could change in the config.txt file is un-commenting the lines:

```
hdmi_group=1 
hdmi_mode=4
```

After you have finished making any changes be sure to reboot the Pi so the changes take effect.

If the solutions above don't work then its a case of trying a new cable. You could also try reinstalling Raspbian. The display you are using might not have audio built in or the audio system its connected to might not be switched on.

Make sure you check all of the obvious stuff first.

Comment: apparently the first command doesn't exist.

sudo rasp-config: command not found.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part, the command is `sudo raspi-config`

Comment: ok, well. I'm looking at the second option and it seems a bit to complicated for someone of my skill set.

Comment: As in you have made the changes I recommended in `raspi-config` and are trying the edit the config.txt file?

Comment: yes. I think I see something. It's saying, "uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in DMT (computer monitor) modes"

Is that what I need?

Comment: That is exactly what you need so remove the `#` before the `hdmi_drive=2` and that will un-comment the line.

Comment: Now that I have done that how do I save it? Because it says to do ^X but when I do that it just adds it into the terminal

Comment: You need to press the CTRL and X keys at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I should have said this earlier, but does it have anything to do with it being hooked up to a TV have anything specific that you must do?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything specific to get audio over HDMI working it should be plug and play. Are you sure you exited the file with saving it? You could also try removing the `#` before `hdmi_group=1` and `hdmi_mode=4`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I saved it. Because every time I go back in to see if I missed something it is the same way I left it. I'll try uncommenting the other ones. Give me a minute

Comment: wait maybe that is the problem. It says that it's only group 1 not group 4

Comment: nope, That isn't a thing

Comment: The running commentary isn't useful, try the things I suggest and then in one comment put what the outcome was.

Comment: The things that you have said to do, do not seem to have any effect. Having gone into the config and changed the things that you have said should work, they haven't. At least I haven't noticed any difference.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't spend anymore time on your problem this evening, I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time, Sorry that I do not seem to be able to understand.

Comment: The audio now works. It seems that when you do the things that I was instructed to do, you must restart the raspberry. Otherwise it'll seem like nothing has happened.

Comment: I've updated my answer so it includes everything discussed here.